# Bind TextBlock to array index programatically

Tags: c#, binding

I am filling a listView dynamically and as a result I am binding each textbox to a property. I have something like:

```
System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory f = new System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock));
f.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.FontWeightProperty, System.Windows.FontWeights.Normal);
Binding myBinding = new Binding("SomeProperty");
f.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

If the listview is filled with an object Animal for example and that class Animal has a property inside named SomeProperty then that column in the listview will contain the value of SomeProperty. What I am trying to do is to bind to a string array for example. Let's say I have the same class Animal and that animal has a string array when I do something like   new Binding("array[1]") it does not bind. It only binds when I do it to a property. Or maybe there is a way of making a property array. It will be nice if I could bind data to an array index

Comment: As I know, you can not do that, you have to select the property name in binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your collection should be

```
       ObservableCollection<string> Animals
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
```

And if you want your listview set dynamically there is easier aproach:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Height="20" Width="100"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
```

And your dataContext should be set to the class with Animals property,
if you really want to do that in C# try with ObservableCollection but I really suggest this solution

Comment: That works too. I maid an indexable array property and It worked. I think that when you bind controls, they can only be binded to properties. Because my previous array was not a property that's why it did not work. I am new to wpf and I like doing most of the things in code.